# jQuery: How to zoom a picture smaller after hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have some table with 6 images. I have now a function for the onclick event. I would like to make another function for the hover. In this function I would like to zoom this picture smaller.

How can I implement this?

Comment: add your code or fiddle it... So that SO can give you a complete solution

Comment: Could you post some code or a fiddle?

Comment: Please create a fiddle or add code in the post to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#theImg").hover(function ()
  {
       $(this).animate({height:"40px", width: "auto"});         
  }
```

That will make the image to animate beautifully into a smaller size

Answer (score 1):

Like this;

```
$( "#imgToZoom" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).css({height: "50px", width: "150px" });

});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hUJy/2/)